# Access EMBED/Object tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, object, embed, flash

Can i use javascript to check whether the video is running or stopped? I have to loop the video but putting loop='true' in the embed doesnt work out well. Is there a javascript method to check if the video is running or stopped?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to embed the video.

Comment: <object width="425" height="350"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/5sw2OvIgoO8"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/5sw2OvIgoO8" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="350"></embed></object>

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what methods the particular object you are using exposes to the JavaScript.

You've tagged this as "flash" - even then it depends on the particular flash object you have, which has to explicitly expose things via the [External Interface](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=0922A).